# Bash script: how to give an alert when current program is killed

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a program using bash script. I'd like to give an alert when this program is killed.

The desired action is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

... # The original program

if killed ; do 
echo "trying to kill the demo program ... "
sleep 5s
echo "demo program killed"
fi
```

Comment: Note that you can't trap all signals. `TERM` can be trapped. `KILL` cannot. So you can log something if someone runs `kill "$yourpid"`, but not on `kill -9 "$yourpid"`.

Comment: See [How to handle signals in bash during synchronous execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856620/how-to-handle-signals-in-bash-during-synchronous-execution), and look for examples in the answers of using `trap`.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect the signal to be delivered only to the running program and *not* to the shell running your script, then the basic synopsis might be:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

sleep 1 &  # The original program
pid="$!"
kill -9 "$pid"  # Pick your lethal signal
wait -n "$pid" && status=0 || status="$?"
((status > 128)) && echo "${pid} got signal $((status - 128))" 1>&2 || :
```

Presumably, here^^^ we run the program in the background, so that we can send it the `kill` signal from the same snippet. In practice you would probably run it in the foreground and then check its `$?` return status instead of the status from `wait -n`.

If the killing signal is delivered to your entire process group, including the shell running your script, that is a different story. For the signal `KILL` (`9`) in particular, there is no way to mask it or report it. When the shell gets it, it dies. For other signals you could set up a `trap` command (see `man bash` for its syntax) to handle the signal gracefully in the script while still being able to detect and report the child process’ death from the signal.

Comment: BTW, `set -e` is generally considered a Bad Idea. See the [exercises in BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) demonstrating how deeply unintuitive its behavior is, and https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/, demonstrating how widely the behavior it triggers differs across shells. The net effect of this is that almost nobody is going to intuitively understand exactly how `set -e` is going to change their script's behavior, so its use makes scripts harder to accurately desk-check. Much better to handle errors explicitly with `|| exit` or `|| return`.

Comment: (`pipefail` is _usually_ a good idea -- with exceptions, see [zcat | head causes pipefail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516177/bash-zcat-head-causes-pipefail) for an example of where it causes surprises -- and `set -u` is [_often_ a good idea](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112); it's only `set -e` that was near-universally recognized as far more trouble than it was worth among the #bash cognoscenti back in the day; see the _combining functions with conditionals_ example in the #105 exercises for a particularly egregious example).

Comment: I agree that `set -e` is sometimes counterintuitive, e.g. in situations like `((a = b + c)) || :` with `|| :` for the case where `((b + c == 0))`. Also, declare -r x="$(possibly_failing)"` does *not* get caught by `set -e`, so one has to split it into `x="$(possibly_failing)"; declare -r x` to achieve the desired behavior. Despite these (and a few more) pitfalls, I must say that the benefits of `set -e` have mostly outweighed its drawbacks in my scripts. For the parts of scripts where I don’t want it on, I usually move them into functions like `blah() { local -; set +e; ... }`

Comment: Of course error conditions should be (almost always) handled using `|| exit $status` or `|| return $status`, but `set -e` is still good for catching the cases when handling is forgotten. It makes debugging easier by pointing at a possible cause of the problem rather than its later consequences. To get `set -e`-like behavior for functions without killing the whole script (i.e. to `return` on errors immediately), one can use, for example, a bit of ugliness like `local -; set +e; trap 'trap - ERR' RETURN; trap return ERR; ...`. Not perfect, but still (IMO) better than failures happening silently.

Comment: `exit` and `return` use `$?` by default, so there's rarely a reason to use `$status` in the case where you want `set -e`-esque behavior from `|| return` or `|| exit`.

Comment: Anyhow, I do think we both understand each others' positions at this point and just happen to disagree :) -- me, I'm less worried about things that can be desk-checked than about code that behaves differently based on context (handles errors in one way when called directly, and in a different way when called from a function whose exit status is used as part of a conditional), as it's nearly impossible to hold the context of _every possible place a function is called_ in one's head when reviewing that function, much less to remember constraints on safe usage when adding new calls.

Comment: Sure, we can agree to differ on that and I also understand your position. Everyone has a slightly different way of coping with the plethora of corner cases in Bash. Understandably, many people prefer to avoid `set -e` to reduce the difference in behavior between scripts and interactive shells. But even in interactive shells I often do `( set -e; fail; on; first; failure; );` before going for lunch.